# Jenkins - worker node agent launch ssh error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, ssh-keys

Recently, have migrated jenkins worker node from one ec2 instance to other using amibackup/restore. But when I tried to launch agent from jenkins master faced the below error. But working fine with existing instance.

```
//"com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.TrileadSSHPublicKeyAuthenticator.getRemainingAuthMethods"//
```

Do I need to change any algorithm/auth settings ?